# Regarding EWS web service for office 365

Tags: c#

I am using EWS web services for fetching emails form office 365 account.
I am getting this error

> The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

I have written this code.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(userData.Version);

if (listener != null)
{
    service.TraceListener = listener;
    service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
    service.TraceEnabled = true;
}

service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userData.EmailAddress, userData.Password);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

if (userData.AutodiscoverUrl == null)
{
    Console.Write(string.Format("Using Autodiscover to find EWS URL for {0}. Please wait... ", userData.EmailAddress));

    service.AutodiscoverUrl(userData.EmailAddress);
    userData.AutodiscoverUrl = service.Url;

    Console.WriteLine("Complete");
}
```

Please check what i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(User, Pwd);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(User, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
service.TraceEnabled = true;
```